# Jenkins hangs on Windows CMD build that has GUI

Tags: jenkins, windows, bash

I am attempting to automate imports and exports of Oracle's PeopleSoft Application Designer. It is a GUI program but it can operate in the windows command line for certain tasks. [This project has examples](https://github.com/psadmin-io/ps-project-git/tree/master/hooks) of how it is used in the command line.

The problem is that despite having parameters to hide the GUI, splash screen and to auto-quit, it is hanging when run in Jenkins. My suspicion is that despite hiding all graphics, the Windows Desktop Window Manager (or something) is still being called and Jenkins has no way to deal with that. I think this because when I execute the command, my CMD window loses focus.

I have tried both with "Execute windows batch command" and with Git Bash, "Execute Shell" and calling cmd.exe.

When I run this in the actual git bash window without hiding the GUI, the GUI still pops up, so the Git Bah program doesn't have the same issue.

**How can I either suppress all GUI in a windows command OR give the program somewhere to put these invisible windows?**

Alternatively, if I am way off base with this assumption that GUI is the problem, how can I troubleshoot?

The command I am using in bash:

`cmd.exe /c "PSIDE.EXE -HIDE -SS NO -SN NO -PJTF TEST_PROJECT_NAME -FP C:\export -CT ORACLE -CD $PS_PROJ_DB -CO $PS_PROJ_USER -CP $PS_PROJ_PASS -QUIT"`

Jenkins is installed directly on the Windows machine where the command is running.

Answer (score 1):

My current, less ideal solution to this is to run Jenkins in a terminal logged in to a desktop rather than as a service. I'd rather not have to do that but it has solved the problem entirely.